# Rails 3 - problem with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, associations

I have following structure:

```
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

and

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :delivery
end
```

and in view

```
<% @shops.each do |shop| %>
  <% @deliveries.each do |dlv| %>
    <div><%= dlv.shop.type %></div>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

getting an error

> undefined method `type' for "#":Shop

I am printing data from table **Shops** and for each item from this table I want to display items from tabe "Deliveries". I though the associations are right, but if I am getting the error above, I am not so sure already...

I would like to ask you about help, what could be wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @shops.each do |shop| %>
  <% shop.delivery.each do |dlv| %>
    <div><%= dlv.type %></div>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

The point of associations is that you can access it from an instance of the model. Note, that `has_many` associations should be pluralized.

Comment: I tried to edit my `has_many :delivery` to `has_many :deliveries` and in view `@shop.deliveries.each do |dlv|`, but getting an error `undefined method `deliveries' for nil:NilClass`. What I am doing still wrong?

Comment: oh, sorry. the `@` in the second line shouldn't be there. Basically you are iterating over each `shop` in `@shops` and then you are iterating over the `deliveries` of **that** `shop`.

Comment: oh, I should have known that (about `@`). Thank you for help, `Femaref`